# How can I swap the Fn key for a Microsoft All-in-One Media keyboard?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys, remapping

I have a [Microsoft Keyboard N9Z model](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-sg/p/all-in-one-media-keyboard). I am using it on Ubuntu 14.04.

The problem is, <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F...</kbd> keys are by default act as media player keys. <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is required to be pressed to get regular function key behavior. For example to get help you need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> together.

There is a way to reverse <kbd>Fn</kbd> key behavior for `Apple` devices [explained here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Corrections), basically it suggest to issue following command:

```
$ echo 2 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode
```

However there is no `hid_apple` folder (of course) in my system and I cannot create a `fnmode` file under `/sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/` folder.

Update:

Output of `lsusb`

```
$ sudo lsusb -v -d 045e:
[sudo] password for destan: 

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0800 Microsoft Corp. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x045e Microsoft Corp.
  idProduct          0x0800 
  bcdDevice            9.34
  iManufacturer           1 Microsoft
  iProduct                2 Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           84
    bNumInterfaces          3
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Keyboard
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      57
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval               4
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        1
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Mouse
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     223
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x000a  1x 10 bytes
        bInterval               1
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        2
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     319
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0020  1x 32 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Is there a way to do this for any other keyboard?

Comment: check out the shell built in bind  http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html

Comment: The "non-apple computer keyboards" vary greatly in their features, so it is not really helpful. USB HID keyboards may have an additional method to switch the key state (which can be exposed by the driver as you demonstrate with `hid_apple`). Can you add the output of the `sudo lsusb -v -d 045e:` command to your question (it will display properties for Microsoft devices, limit the output to your keyboard if you have multiple entries).

Comment: @Lekensteyn I've added the output. I have only one Microsoft device which is the keyboard.

Answer (score 5):

Just press <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>Capslock</kbd>. And everything will be just fine.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for the way to do this in software (i.e. to enable this mode without physically pressing any key, i.e. to enable this mode without having to remember to press Fn - Capslock (which no one in their right mind would have guessed))

Answer (score 2):

The **fn** key is set by default. I mean if you want that **fn** key shouldn't be required for common functionalities of **" F1, F2, F3,......."**   keys, follow these steps:

1. Go to **BIOS settings**
2. Navigate to the **System Configuration** option
3. Then navigate to the **Action Keys Mode** option, and then press the "enter" key to display the **Enable / Disable menu**
4. **Disable** that option

Comment: no, this only works for built-in keyboards, not for external keyboards. BIOS settings can have no effect on this case because the external keyboard itself determines the keycode that it sends.